# Python: Indent all lines of a string except first while preserving linebreaks?

Tags: python, string, text, indentation, word-wrap

I want to indent all lines of a multi-line string except the first, without wrapping the text.

For example, I want to turn:

```
A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
long mutiline
string
```

into:

```
A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
     long multiline
     string
```

I have tried

```
textwrap.fill(string, width=999999999999, subsequent_indent='   ',)
```

But this still puts all of the text on one line. Thoughts?

Comment: From the docs for `subsequent_indent`: "String that will be prepended to all lines of wrapped output."  Since nothing is being wrapped, nothing is being indented.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to replace the newline character `'\n'` with a new line character plus the white spaces  `'\n    '` and save it to a variable (since `replace` won't change your original string, but return a new one with the replacements).

```
string = string.replace('\n', '\n    ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
In [21]: s = 'abc\ndef\nxyz'

In [22]: print s
abc
def
xyz

In [23]: print '\n    '.join(s.split('\n'))
abc
    def
    xyz
```

?

**edit:** Alternatively (HT @Steven Rumbalski):

```
In [24]: print s.replace('\n', '\n    ')
abc
    def
    xyz
```

Comment: Why `split` and `join` when you can simply `replace`?

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson:  It would seem unpythonic to use `textwrap` for a job that doesn't need any wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

The bare replace mentioned by [@steven-rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518031/python-indent-all-lines-of-a-string-except-first-while-preserving-linebreaks#comment27231035_18518238) is going to be the most efficient way to accomplish this, but it's not the only way.

Here's another solution using list comprehensions. If the text has already been split into a list of lines, this will be much faster than running `join()`, `replace()` and `splitlines()`

```
text = """A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
long mutiline
string"""

lines = text.splitlines()
indented = ['    ' + l for l in lines]
indented[0] = lines[0]
indented = '\n'.join(indented)
```

The list could be modified in place, but there's a significant performance cost versus using a second variable. It's also moderately faster to indent all the lines and then swap out the first line in another operation.

There's also the `textwrap` module. I disagree that using textwrap for indentation is unpythonic. If the lines are joined in a single string containing newlines, that string is inherently wrapped. Indentation is a logical extension of text wrapping, so textwrap makes sense to me.

Except that it's slow. Really, really slow. Like 15x slower.

Python 3 added `indent` to `textwrap` which makes indenting without re-wrapping very easy. There's certainly a more elegant way of handling the lambda predicate, but this does exactly what the original question was asking for.

```
indented = textwrap.indent(text, '    ', lambda x: not text.splitlines()[0] in x )
```

Here are some `timeit` results of the various methods.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(r"text.replace('\n', '\n    ')", setup='text = """%s"""' % text)
0.5123521030182019
```

The two list comprehension solutions:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(r"indented = ['    ' + i for i in lines]; indented[0] = lines[0]", setup='lines = """%s""".splitlines()' % text)
0.7037646849639714

>>> timeit.timeit(r"indented = [lines[0]] + ['    ' + i for i in lines[1:]]", setup='lines = """%s""".splitlines()' % text)
1.0310905870283023
```

And here's the unfortunate `textwrap` result:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(r"textwrap.indent(text, '    ', lambda x: not text.splitlines()[0] in x )", setup='import textwrap; text = """%s"""' % text)
7.7950868209591135
```

I thought some of that time could be the horribly inefficient predicate, but even with that removed, `textwrap.indent` is still more than 8 times slower than a bare replace.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(r"textwrap.indent(text, '    ')", setup='import textwrap; text = """%s"""' % text)
4.266149697010405
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.3 (introduced `indent`) and later, you can do this:

```py
from textwrap import indent

def not_first():
    """Creates a function returning False only the first time."""
    _first_time_call = True

    def fn(_) -> bool:
        nonlocal _first_time_call

        res = not _first_time_call
        _first_time_call = False
        return res

    return fn


def indent_except_first_line(s: str, indent_string: str) -> str:
    return indent(s, indent_string, not_first())
```

Every time you call `not_first`, it creates a new function with a built-in flag which check if it's being called for the first time.

`indent` uses that generated function to decide whether to indent each line in the supplied string.